# Summarize rows into one total

Tags: r

I know this is super simple, but I always have trouble with this.

```
site     diagnosis    week   value
Site A   anxiety      total  13
Site B   anxiety      total  1
Site A   depression   total  27
Site C   depression   total  18
```

I want to get the data in a state where I can plot it by diagnosis. I don't care about site or week, just want the sum of all values for each diagnosis.

I have tried

```
df %>% 
  group_by(diagnosis) %>% 
  summarize(
    total = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

But I get the error

> "Error in `summarize()`:
> ! Problem while computing `total_value = sum(n, na.rm = TRUE)`.
> ℹ The error occurred in group 1: diagnosis = "anxiety".
> Caused by error in `sum()`:
> ! invalid 'type' (closure) of argument
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred."

Comment: Check that you are actually using `dplyr::summarize`. Your code works correctly on my machine. Or check that `value` is numeric, and not a character column

Comment: It was a character, thank you!